# How to calculate frequency of word in text

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I implement javascript function to calculate frequency of word in text

```
frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']);

should return {"bar": 2, "foo": 3}
```

Comment: I don't think "rotate" is the term you're looking for.  "count" maybe.  In any case, you don't have an array to begin with, you have a string.  Is it always space-delimited?

Comment: @Brad the second parameter is an array

Comment: @bto.rdz I see that, but the whole point of the function is to parse a string.  That's what I'm getting at.  Word count with a filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do that

```
function frequencies(str, opts) {
    var o = {};
    opts.forEach(function(opt) { o[opt] = 0; });
    str.split(/\s+/).forEach(function(x) { if (x in o) o[x]++; });

    return o;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/67yxzhx7/1/)

Comment: before split is good to clean up str  str.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, ' ').replace(/s+/g, ' ')

Comment: @kAlmAcetA - no need, it checks the array for matches anyway

Comment: @adeneo this array - to be more specific - try this string "foo, foo bar, foo   bar buz"

Comment: @kAlmAcetA - Then you have commas to worry about, the OP's code has no such thing, it's like saying try this string `foobar bar,,foo footerot, barkeeper`, it's just not the same thing anymore

Comment: @adeneo dont want to argue but OP's question didn't mention about delimiter, just count tf. Your answer is ok - for given example only (with whitespace delimiter). EOT

Answer (score 0):

If you can use underscore/lodash its as simple as:

```
function frequencies(str) {
  return _.countBy(str.split(' '));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function frequencies(str, words){
    var ret = {}, split = str.split(' ');

    for(var i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        var currentWord = split[i];
        if(!currentWord || !~words.indexOf(currentWord)) continue;
        ret[currentWord] = !ret[currentWord] ? 1 : ret[currentWord]+1;
    }

    return ret;
}

console.log(frequencies('foo foo bar foo   bar buz', ['foo', 'bar']));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uqgtqy01/1/